# arrow up key and scroll up now jump UP my entire page

Tags: bugs

Been looking for what is causing this but have yet to find anything. Recently for some reason the up arrow and a normal scroll up jumps all the way from the bottom of the page (or wherever you happen to be) all the way to the top of the page. The down arrow and scroll down work fine. It is only the up arrow and scroll up that jump all the way to the top of the page.

Anyone ever come across this? know what could be going on?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic since it's about [coding](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Thanks for sharing what you figured out however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the issue was:

Missing closing `</div>` so it caused arrow keys and scroll up to jump all the way to the top of that page.

Comment: I am not sure why your answer got a down-vote. That did not make sense to me. So I up-voted it and the question because I want to encourage you and it was the right thing to do. I am glad you came here, found an answer, then shared it with us. If nothing else, that deserves some gratitude from he community. So here is my gratitude. Welcome. Keep coming back. There are a lot of good people here and some real experts. I am glad you came to join us.